# Display a user friendly message in user event script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to do some validations using a user event script but I want to show user some meaningful error instead of the default 'suitescript' error at the end. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

User Events are server-side, so there is no UI in which to display a message. You cannot validate date on `beforeSubmit` and display a message. If you want to validate as the user saves and show them feedback, you need to use the `saveRecord` entry point on a Client Script.

You *can* do this via the `beforeLoad` entry point because it receives a reference to the `Form` in context, which has an `addPageInitMessage` entry. Check out the Help docs for this method to see if it will work for your case.

Answer (score 1):

As @erictgrubaugh suggested you cannot use **User Event** for validation.

If you want to perform validation and stop form submission, you need to use **ClientScript** with `saveRecord` and you can perform all of your validations here. If current record does not passes your validation you show user error using  `N/ui/message` with some description and if everything is correct return `true`.

To stop current record from being saved, return `false` from `saveRecord`.

Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4497735093.html) out to see how to use `N/ui/message` and [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4410693749.html) for further reading on `saveRecord`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "throw" to display error message on before submit.

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide a code example in your answer.